# Get fullname of user from django user model

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get the data from django's user model and print the full name of a user from it.

**view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def Showfullname (request):
    fullname =  request.user.get_full_name()
    context = {'fullname':fullname}
    return render(request, 'main/base.html', context)
```

the line for it from **urls.py**

```
url(r'^name$', views.Showfullname, name='Showfullname'),
```

and then the div that is the target in my main files, where I already have a is authenticated check in a parent template.

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{% url 'main:Showfullname' %}" readonly />
            <i class="glyphicons glyphicons-car form-control-feedback"></i>
</div>
```

Right now it prints

/ in the input when it should be printing dan dan or admin admin

Comment: You should read a Django tutorial as you are clearly missing some basics. Change the relevant part to `placeholder="{{ fullname }}"` for starters. You don't even need to use a view for this purpose as you can simply use `{{ user.get_full_name }}` in any template when you include `django.core.context_processors.auth` context processor in your `settings.py`.

Comment: ^^ This is the correct answer.

Comment: @Selcuk write it as answer. This is is correct and perfect solution.

Comment: I am aware that I can use {{ user.get_full_name }} but I wanted to know if there was a way to get the same result using a view-based approach. I do thank you all for the responses though.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `{{full_name}}` in your Django template. Also, if your user is authenticated you can use `{{request.user.get_full_name}}` in the template.

Answer (score 3):

And from django models you can get it with by using simple method like this..

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ExampleUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def full_name(self):
        return self.user.get_full_name()
```

Answer (score 1):

In the template, you can use this to get the full name

```
<h3>{{request.user.get_full_name}}</h3>
```

it returns the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between. [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/#:%7E:text=get_full_name()%C2%B6,space%20in%20between.)